# Remove Rows Based on Dataframe

Tags: r

I've entered my data into R using the following command...

```
Country_Data <- read.csv("Country Data.csv", row.names = 1)
```

With the following result...

```
               Criteria 1    Criteria 2    Criteria 3
[Country A]        x             x              x
[Country B]        x             x              x
[Country C]        x             x              x
...
[Country Z]        x             x              x
```

In the process of my coding I created a subset `influential_countries` similar to the following...

```
           Criteria 4    
[Country E]        x     
[Country F]        x       
[Country J]        x
```

I would like to delete this subset of countries from Country_Data. In other words, I would like to remove Countries E, F, and J. I attempted the following code without much luck...

```
Country_Data_clean <- Country_Data[-c(influential_countires), ]
```

Any suggestions on how to remove would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try with `anti_join` if it is a column.  or else `Country_Data[!row.names(Country_Data) %in% row.names(influential_countries),]`\

Comment: Thank you, but I actually tried that command based on a previous search and still no luck. Nothing was deleted from Country_Data.

Comment: If the commented code didn't work, and none of the five answers provided in the duplicate questions worked, then the impetus is on you to provide a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including consumable data (yours is close), what code you tried, and what your actual results are.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  Would this count as a reproducible data?  `data(mtcars)

subset<-subset(mtcars, mpg >= quantile(mtcars$mpg)[4])

mtcars[!row.names(mtcars) %in% row.names(subset),]

`

Comment: So I was successful in getting this code to achieve my desired outcome in the reproducible data, 
`df <- mtcars[!(rownames(mtcars) %in% rownames(subset )),]`
But could not get it to work in my own data set. Hmmm...

Comment: That does count as reproducible data, but apparently it isn't *good* meaningful data. That is, it does not representative of what you need. It could be due to `factor`s, lack of row names, or several other things. Unless and until you provide actual consumable data (read the link), however, there's nothing we can do.